# AWS lambda with Kafka trigger generate duplicate

Tags: apache-kafka, lambda, triggers, duplicates

I have a AWS lambda who has a Kafka trigger. During CPR testing, it generated duplicates: In the Kafka topic, there was 100000 messages but the lambda processed 110000 (rounding). After validating the processed messages, I notice that there are duplicates (identical messages have been processed several times).

How can I avoid this problem?

Some parameter of the trigger:

- Batch size: 100
- Starting position: Trim horizon
- Batch window: 10

When I process a small volume of data, I don't have this problem.

Comment: Is it documented that the Kafka trigger will be exactly once? It should be expected to have at least once processing, which means some records could get handled more than once, just that none will be missed